# Android logcat errors on project

Tags: android, project, logcat

I'm trying to run a project in Android but it crashes upon trying to execute it: I don't really understand the logCat messages I get so I wanted to see if someone could help me out in understanding them.

Here are some of my errors:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: MAIN
java.lang.RunTimeException: Unable to start activity componentInfo (com.example.logger/com.example.logger.ThirdActivity):java.lang.RuntimeException: your content must have a ListView whose id attribe is 'android.R.id.list';
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list';
at.com.example.logger.ThirdActivity.onCreate (ThirdActivity:java:18)
```

**Android Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.logger"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.logger.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name="com.example.logger.SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_second"
            ></activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.logger.ThirdActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_third" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**End manifest**

**Main Activity**

```
package com.example.logger;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    attachHandlers();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


private void attachHandlers() {
    findViewById(R.id.login).setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    if(arg0.getId() == R.id.login)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);    
    }

}
```

}

**End Main Activity**

**SecondActivity**

```
package com.example.logger;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
private static final int NUM_PAGES = 10;

private ViewPager mpager;

private MyPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
private int [] pics = {R.drawable.android_interfaz_layout_estructura_final, R.drawable.baixa, R.drawable.baixada, R.drawable.greenprogressbar,
        R.drawable.layout_keyboard, R.drawable.linerlay, R.drawable.merge1, R.drawable.o2zds, R.drawable.regbd,
        R.drawable.s7qrs};

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    mPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(null);
    mpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewer);
    mpager.setAdapter (mPagerAdapter);
}

public void showImage (int position, View view)
{
    //View is your view that you returned from instantiateItem 
    //and position is it's position in array you can get the image resource id 
    //using this position and set it to the ImageView
}

private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter
{

    SecondActivity activity;
    public MyPagerAdapter (SecondActivity activity){
        this.activity=activity;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return pics.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
        ImageView view = new ImageView (SecondActivity.this);
        view.setImageResource (pics[position]);
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPrimaryItem (ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
    {
        super.setPrimaryItem (container, position, object);
        activity.showImage(position,(View)object);
    }

    }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second, menu);
    return true;
}


private OnClickListener mPageClickListener = new OnClickListener()
{
 public void onClick (View v)
 {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     //aquí anirà la funció per traslladar la image de la gallery a la pantalla
     Integer picId = (Integer) v.getTag();
     mpager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     mpager.setCurrentItem(v.getId());

 }

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

    };
```

}

**End Second Activity**

**Third Activity**

```
package com.example.logger;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ThirdActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);
    final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    String[] values = new String[] {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", 
            "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen",
            "Twenty"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_third, android.R.id.list, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);


}

    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.third, menu);
    return true;

    }

    public void attachButton()
    {
        findViewById(R.id.add).setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

}

**End Third Activity**

**Activity_Main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Login"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  
        android:background="@drawable/shapes"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        />

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/input_u"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        />

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_below="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/input_p"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**End Activity_Main.xml**

**Activity_Second.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity" >


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/viewer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         android:layout_weight="0.70"
        />

    <ImageView 

        android:id="@+id/big_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/viewer"
         android:layout_weight="0.30"

        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**End Activity_Second.xml**

```
**Activity_Third.xml**

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ThirdActivity" >

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/add"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:text="@string/add"
       />

   <ListView 
       android:id="@+id/list"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_below="@+id/add"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"

          ></ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**End Activity_Third.xml**

I'd very grateful if someone could help me figure out what I'm doing wrong on this project.

Yours sincerely,

Mauro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the id of your ListView

from

```
android:id="@+id/list"
```

to

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Android cannot find your `ListView` because you given it the incorrect id.

Answer (score 0):

it say that in the onCreate method of ThirdActivity.java, you need to set a content that contains a ListView with id "android.R.id.list"

Your content is describe in the third_activity.xml file.

So in third_activity.xml, your list view should have this ID:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
```

and not

```
android:id="@+id/list"
```

(Check this post if needed [Listview error: "Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696506/listview-error-your-content-must-have-a-listview-whose-id-attribute-is-androi))